# std::memory_order_relaxed with fetch_add

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, relaxed-atomics

I'm trying gain a deeper understanding of relaxed memory ordering. Per CPP reference, there is no synchronization, however atomicity is still guaranteed. Doesn't atomicity in this case require some form of sync, e.g. how does `fetch_add()` below guarantee that only one thread will update the value from `y` to `y+1`, particularly if writes can be visible out of order to different threads? Is there an implicit sync associated with `fetch_add` ?

> memory_order_relaxed  Relaxed operation: there are no synchronization or ordering constraints imposed on other reads or writes, only this operation's atomicity is guaranteed (see Relaxed ordering below)

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

static uint64_t incr = 100000000LL;

atomic<uint64_t> x;

void g()
{
   for (long int i = 0; i < incr; ++i)
   {
      x.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
   }
}

int main()
{
   int Nthreads = 4;
   vector<thread> vec;
   vec.reserve(Nthreads);
   for (auto idx = 0; idx < Nthreads; ++idx)
      vec.push_back(thread(g));
   for(auto &el : vec)
      el.join();
   // Does not trigger
   assert(x.load() == incr * Nthreads);
}
```

Comment: "other" in the quote about "other reads or writes" refers to other variables.. I think I see how it can be misread

Answer (score 2):

"Synchronization" has a very specific meaning in C++.

It refers to following. Let's say:

1. Thread A reads/writes to memory X. (doesn't have to be atomic)
2. Thread A writes to atomic variable Y. (must be a `release` or `seq_cst` write)
3. Thread B reads the variable Y, and sees the value previously written by A. (must be an `acquire` or `seq_cst` read)

   At this point, operations (2) and (3) are said to **synchronize with** each other.
4. Thread B reads/writes to memory X. (doesn't have to be atomic)

   Normally this would cause a data race with thread A (undefined behavior), but it doesn't because of the synchronization.

This only works with `release`/`acquire`/`seq_cst` operations, and not `relaxed` operations. That's what the quote means.